# Angular.js - How to create views without adding ng-view directive in the HTML file?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

How to use views without adding `ng-view` directive in the HTML file?

We can create an Angular.js app without using `ng-app` in the HTML code by manually bootstrapping Angular.js project, like the following:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
```

Similarly can we do this for `ng-view` as well? If yes, how?

Comment: Basically, I am looking for a way where to create Angular.js application without having to edit the HTML file.

Comment: Not sure what your goal is, but you could add a `<div ng-view>` element to the DOM using vanilla JavaScript, and then bootstrap the angular application.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks. However that is my problem statement here, I dont want to use `<div ng-view>` inside of my HTML file. I want to do it from my JavaScript code but not my DOM manipulation. I am sort of trying to keep my HTML clean.

Comment: I don't understand anything of what you're doing. How is having a fiv ng-view not clean? How is adding one dynamically not clean? Angular is based on directives, and directives consist in adding attributes and elements to the dom. If you don't like it, you shouldn't be using angular.

Comment: I know that directives are the very core part of Angular.js and it is how things work in Angular.js. However, I am trying to explore if there is a way to do it via javascript instead of doing it the HTML directive way. Like how `ng-app` can be ignored by not using it as directive inside the HTML file.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You're fighting against the framework, which has been designed precisely around this idea. That's even where the name comes from. The tag line of AngularJS is "HTML enhanced for web apps". And you're trying not to enhance the HTML. You won't go anywhere.

Comment: When Angular loads, it searches for `ng-app` directive to bootstrap an app. If you want to do so manually, Angular provides a `.bootstrap` method. I don't understand what equivalency you are looking for with `ng-view`? Do you want a `bootstrapView` method? If so, following @JBNizet's advice and add a `<div ng-view>` with Javascript, if you must, and then call `bootstrap`

Comment: Thanks guys! Your arguments were insightful :) BUT, I was investigating that if we could avoid using `ng-app` by using `.bootstrap` method, then is there a way where we could probably avoid using all or most of the other derivatives. I am still looking for that answer for knowledge and discussion sake.  In case I dont get an answer I will close this thread considering that there is no way to make this work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your clean HTML would look like? Then perhaps an example of what you would like to happen to the DOM based on the example you provided. Anything can be done, just might be a bit hackie on the js side.